# What actually happens int i, k; k &= i;

Tags: c++

As a beginner learning pointers, I wrote something like

```
int i = 1,
    j = 2,
    k;

k &= i;
i = 3;
```

Expecting `k` to point to `i`, however, I soon found that the mistake is that `k` is not a `int` pointer, just an `int`. But it compiles and run why?

Comment: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/5bk6ya5x(v=vs.71).aspx

Comment: I think you read `k&=i` as `k=&i`. They're very different, even more different than `i-=1` and `i=-1`.

Answer (score 21, accepted):

```
k &= i;
```

is the short form for

```
k = k & i;
```

where `&` is bitwise `and`. It has nothing to do with pointers.

If you want to make `k` to point to `i`, you need to make it a pointer:

```
// v
int* k;
```

and them to make it point to `i`:

```
k = &i; // NOTE: different from k &= i;
```

Answer (score 2):

&= is the same as k = k & i.  & is the bitwise AND operator.

Answer (score 2):

`k &= i` is equivalent to `k = k & i` which is a bitwise and operation.